# how to change MediaElement source when ListPicker_SelectionChanged?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, casting

I'm trying to bind item from list picker to MediaElement Source when user I have the uri store in ListPickerItem Tag my problem I want to change the bleep.Source when ListPicker_SelectionChanged but my problem how to selected and cast it ?

```
private void ListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    bleep.Source = lp_sound.SelectedItem.ToString();
}



<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <MediaElement x:Name="bleep" Source="soundFiles\ROAR.wav" AutoPlay="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonPlay" Content="play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,404,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ButtonPlay_Click"/>
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lp_sound" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="408" SelectionChanged="ListPicker_SelectionChanged">

        <toolkit:ListPickerItem x:Name="BestRoar" Content="Sound1" Tag="soundFiles\ROAR.wav" ></toolkit:ListPickerItem>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to get results. I assumed that you have used local media file in your listpicker.

```
private void ListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e){

ListPickerItem item = lp_sound.SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;

if(item!=null)
   bleep.Source = new Uri(Convert.ToString(item.Tag), UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Hope this will help.